# How to get children of parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

]Hi
can you please tell me how to get count children of parent element ?In my demo I add submenu by pressing "add" button it generate submenu of "first level" in left panel .I need count children if user click to "first level"

In a pic if user have 3 children .If it is click "First level" it show "3",If user click "menu_tc_1" it show 0..or same in "menu_tc_2", "menu_tc_3"

http://jsfiddle.net/rajumjib/PZR7N/6/.

```
$(document).on('click'," ul li > a",function(e){
 alert('----'+$(this).siblings().length);  // working fine
     alert('----'+$(this).siblings().first().attr('id')); //not working ?


})
```

can I gey ID of first child ..?

Comment: I am getting undefined when I click to any item

Comment: use `$(this).parent().children().length`

Comment: can please use fiddle

Comment: it is giving more than 1

Comment: Sorry, change to `$(this).siblings().length`

Comment: working fine ..can we get id of first children

Comment: `$(this).siblings().first().prop('id')`

Comment: Not working ..undefined come

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, answer with both requirements:

```
$(document).on('click'," ul li > a",function(e){
     alert($(this).siblings().length)
     var id=$(this).parent().attr("id") || $(this).parents("ul").attr("id");
    alert(id);
})
```